# I only want to remove quotes from the first line

Tags: powershell

I am trying to only remove the quotes from the first line of my report.  The rest of the report, quotes are fine.  I tried this, but it deleted everything after the first line:

```
(gc daily_report_yyyymmdd.csv -First 1) |
    % {$_ -replace '"', ""} |
    Out-File daily_report_yyyymmdd.csv -Fo -En Ascii
```

Header

```
ORDER_ID,"PRIORITY_STATUS","PRODUCT_CLASS","PLAN_NAME","CONTRACT_ID","GROUP_NAME","CREATION_DATE","TECH_RESPONSE_DATE","RPH_RESPONSE_DATE","CLOSE_DATE","MEMBER_ID","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME","DRUGNAME","PHYSICIAN_FIRST_NAME","PHYSICIAN_LAST_NAME","NPI","RPH First Name","RPH Last Name","CSR First Name","CSR Last Name","QA First Name","QA Last Name","OutBound Call Notes","RFI Sent","COV_DETERM_TYPE","ORIGIN_OF_REQUEST","FORMULARYSTATUS","BENEFIT","ORDER_STATUS","RATIONALEBRIEFDESC","EARLY_CLOSE_CODE","TAT from Order Create (Hours)","TAT from Fax Receipt (Hours)"
```

First Line

```
2727770,"Standard","TESTMAI","TESTMAI","PIZZA ","DOUGH","2017-11-29 18:11:18.816000","2017-12-01 08:53:30.000000","2017-11-07 09:15:32.000000","2017-12-01 08:53:30.665000","123456789","TEST","USER","Bystolic 10 mg tablet","TEST","PEOPLE","1234657984","TESTER","TEST","TESTER","TEST","TESTER","TEST","","N","","Provider Fax","On Formulary","Pharmacy Benefit","Early Close","The medication requested is a non-preferred medication.  The member must try/fail at least one preferred agent for a period of 30 days or more before approval of a non-preferred agent. The preferred a","ELCL","38","38"
```

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` rather than `Get-Content`. It will give you objects that you can sort and filter.

Comment: I don't think that will work.  My header is pretty crazy and some of the characters would create an issue.  I guess another work around is if i could remove the CR from the first line.

Comment: You're sure it won't work? Have you tried it? How about correcting the header, rewriting the file, then using `Import-Csv`?

Comment: I did try and it didn't seem to work.  The problem is, i can append the header using type>, but it adds CRLF to the file.  I only need LF.  If I let the SSIS package runs, it puts " in the header (text qualifier).  No way around it.

Comment: *I am trying to only remove the quotes from the first line of my report.* Why? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: You tried what and what didn't work? How did it not work? Make sure you describe the real problem and not your attempted solution.

Comment: I have a report that can only have LF.  I am exporting via SSIS and it's adds CRLF or LF (but quotes around text).  I know this will always be the first line and it will almost always have "

Comment: I created a test CSV file with the header line and first line of data you posted and saved the file with LF only line terminator. `Import-Csv` works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up converting the DOS to UNIX in PowerShell and it took care of my CR issue:

```
$csvdata = [io.file]::ReadAllText('in.csv') | % {$_ -replace "`r",""}
[io.file]::WriteAllLines('out.csv', $csvdata)
```

Comment: So your question was really: "How do I change the line terminator of a text file?" (Rather different, to put it mildly, than what you actually wrote in your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting one line and then writing it back to the same file, essentially overwriting the whole file with that line. Result: everything else gets deleted.

I am not too concerned with what you are trying to achieve here. If you are sure it is always going to be the 1st line you can try this.

```
$File = gc daily_report_yyyymmdd.csv
$File[1] -replace '"', ""
$File | Out-File daily_report_yyyymmdd.csv -Fo -En Ascii
```

Doesn't leave a lot of room for scalability

Comment: Still coming through with ".  Nuts, really.  I will add the header and one line and you can see if it works for you